# adb devices - not show iphone device

Tags: android, iphone, linux-mint

Linux Mint 19

I pluggin my iphone device.

Here result in Nemo :

[image]

[image]

Nice.
But when I use command: `adb devices` not show any connected devices.

```
adb devices
List of devices attached
```

Comment: `adb` is for Android devices. Do you have an Android-powered iPhone?

Comment: @CommonsWare. No, when I can get it?

Comment: Probably never. But, once you do, it should have `adb` support.